# Groovy date parse issue

Tags: date, groovy

date.parse() method of groovy detects date DD and year yyyy correctly but is unable to detect the month as mmm.. As in

```
println new Date().parse("DD-MMM-yyyy", '22-MAR-2011')
```

yields output as

```
Sat Jan 22 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2011
```

Why is the month march as MAR picked up as Jan? What can I do to make it detect the month in mmm format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is actualy that you are using `DD` - that means day in year

Correct way:

```
println new Date().parse("dd-MMM-yyyy", '22-MAR-2011')
```

Quick tip when formatting dates try using the reverse and see what comes out:

```
println new Date().format("dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

Groovy uses [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)  under the hood but that's not that important since most date libraries use the same format conventions.